# Is “various/many kinds of” implied in “plenty of”?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Does “plenty of” imply “many kinds of” in the following sentence?

Our company made good money this year so our New Year party was the best wing-ding. There was plenty to eat and drink and most of us stayed later than we ever had before.

Thank you.

Comment: No. It just implies that there was enough for everyone, although one might infer that there was variety as well as quantity.

Comment: There's no "plenty of" in that sentence.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy - doesn't plenty to in the example imply 'plenty of food to' in turn? With respect to the context of the usage.?

Comment: @VanpramP: Yes, *probably*. But the question should really start with what's actually there, then ask if the understanding of what that implies is correct and what that actually means, rather than skipping ahead with the assumption that the asker is correctly identifying the elided words.

Answer (score 1):

No. Plenty doesn't imply different varieties/kinds.
The meaning of plenty is availability in abundance.

Check out the following definitions from Google:

> pronoun: plenty
>
> > 1.a large or sufficient amount or quantity; more than enough.
>
> "I would have plenty of time to get home before my parents arrived"
>
> noun
>   noun: plenty
>
> 1. a situation in which food and other necessities are available in sufficiently large quantities.
>
>    "such natural phenomena as famine and plenty"
>
> adverb
>   informal
>
> adverb: plenty
>
> 1. used to emphasize the degree of something.
>
>    "she has plenty more ideas"

The first definition suits your example well.

It just means that the food was in abundance/more than enough for everyone gathered there.